# How do I select tables in a SQL Server that have a field Shape that is an INT type?

Tags: sql-server

I've got some tables where Shape is a geometry, and some where its an int. I want to find those with int type Shape fields and fix them. I'm a bit of a dummy with T-SQL.

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example of each of these tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use information_schema.columns to find columns (fields) that have a data type of int and a name of Shape. For Example:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME, 
    DATA_TYPE
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
(DATA_TYPE = 'int') AND 
(COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Shape%')
```